# Preallocate structure of cells in matlab

Tags: matlab, structure, cell

I use a structure called `test` with the following "layout" (result of `whos test, test`)

```
  Name      Size              Bytes  Class     Attributes
  test      1x1             8449048  struct              
test = 
     timestamp: {[7.3525e+05]  [7.3525e+05]  [7.3525e+05]}
    timeseries: {[44000x8 double]  [44000x8 double]  [44000x8 double]}
```

For speed issues, I want to preallocate that with zeros.
I found some ways, which result in other "layouts":

```
test2=struct('timestamp',cell(1,3),'timeseries',cell(1,3));
test3=struct('timestamp',{0,0,0},'timeseries',{zeros(44000,8),zeros(44000,8),zeros(44000,8)});
tempstamp={0,0,0};
tempseries={zeros(44000,8),zeros(44000,8),zeros(44000,8)};
test4=struct('timestamp',tempstamp,'timeseries',tempseries);
whos test2 test3 test4,test2,test3,test4
```

resulting in

```
  Name       Size              Bytes  Class     Attributes
  test2      1x3                 176  struct              
  test3      1x3             8448824  struct              
  test4      1x3             8448824  struct              
test2 = 
1x3 struct array with fields:
    timestamp
    timeseries
test3 = 
1x3 struct array with fields:
    timestamp
    timeseries
test4 = 
1x3 struct array with fields:
    timestamp
    timeseries
```

When issuing the commands `test5.timestamp=tempstamp;test5.timeseries=tempseries;whos test5,test5` one gets

```
 Name       Size              Bytes  Class     Attributes
  test5      1x1             8449048  struct              
test5 = 
     timestamp: {[0]  [0]  [0]}
    timeseries: {[44000x8 double]  [44000x8 double]  [44000x8 double]}
```

Thus reproducing the "layout" in `test`. This is strange, isn't it?
Further using `test2.timestamp{2}=now` is not working as with `test3`and `test4`.
Okay, this is described in the documentation `help struct`, but how can I preallocate such `1x1 struct` like `test` or `test5` within one line? Best without those `temp*` variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `struct` with cells to init a field with cell requires depth-2 cell:

```
test=struct('timestamp',{cell(1,3)},'timeseries',{cell(1,3)});
```

or

```
test3 = struct( 'timestamp', { {0,0,0}},...
                'timeseries',{ {zeros(44000,8),zeros(44000,8),zeros(44000,8)} });
```

For reference see [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) doc the example regarding "Fields that Contain Cell Arrays".

Comment: Thanks Shai for the precise and fast answer.

Answer (score 2):

One more possibility (that I find easier to read) is to init each field separately.

```
test3.timestamp = {0, 0, 0};
test3.timeseries = {zeros(44000,8), zeros(44000,8), zeros(44000,8)};
```

Comment: This is nearly the same as `my` idea for `test5`.