# MATLAB creating of struct-vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, cell, dimension

Given some data - for example (in my case) - like the following tabular

```
Name  |pos_x|pos_y|pos_z
------------------------
Point1|   .1|   .1|   .2
Point2|  0.0|  0.0|   .1
Middle|   .1|   .2|   .1
Point3|  0.0|    1|  0.0
```

and maybe after importing that data from excel all values are stored in a cell array (lets call it `celldata`).
For testing purposes this cell could be created with the line

```
celldata={'Point1' .1 .1 .2;'Point2' 0 0 .1;'Middle' .1 .2 .1;'Point3' 0 1 0}
```

For this example the cell is of size 4x4.

At the moment I'm creating a structure with the following lines

```
point.name=char(celldata(:,1));
point.posxyz=cell2mat(celldata(:,2:4));
```

This results in `point size 1x1 Class struct`. I'm looking for an efficient way to generate it as `point size 4x1 Class struct` - thus one element for each line in the tabular above - all with the same inner structure: a name and the coordinates.
I already tried `cell2struct`, but that is only able to unfold along one dimension without grouping some colums together - as far as I tried.
Further, this is not a duplicate of [Preallocate structure of cells in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376903/preallocate-structure-of-cells-in-matlab) as in this case here, I have many different columns - or maybe even a dynamic count of columns.

Comment: do you think that `dataset` would be any helpful?

Comment: I think it would be fine for looping over the elements: `for punkt=point,disp([punkt.name ':' num2str(norm(punkt.posxyz))]),end` as an example. Especially one does not need to check how many elements there are. Do you know anything better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cellData = {'Name', 'pos_x', 'pos_y'; 'Harry', 34, 2; 'Bernard', 5, 11}
```

Then

```
for col = 1:size(cellData ,2)
    fieldName = cellData{1, col};
    c = cellData (2:end, col);
    [point(1:length(c)).(fieldName)] = c{:};
end
```

Now

```
point(1)

ans = 

     Name: 'Harry'
    pos_x: 34
    pos_y: 2

point(2)

ans = 

     Name: 'Bernard'
    pos_x: 5
    pos_y: 11
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to only have 2 fields, i.e. `Name` and `posxyz` then:

```
 [M, N] = size(celldata);
 names = celldata(:,1);
 [point(1:M).Name] = names{:};
 xyz = mat2cell(cell2mat(celldata(:,2:end)), ones(M,1), N - 1);
 [point(1:M).posxyz] = xyz{:};
```

now for `celldata={'Point1' .1 .1 .2;'Point2' 0 0 .1;'Middle' .1 .2 .1;'Point3' 0 1 0}`

```
point(1)

ans = 

          Name: 'Point1'
        posxyz: [0.1000 0.1000 0.2000]

point(2)

ans = 

      Name: 'Point2'
    posxyz: [0 0 0.1000]
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan for this idea, but I really don't like the need to assign the names (for example) one by another. Please think about a table with some hundreds or more lines. Further ideas?

Comment: Adding could of course be done like done within `rmfield.m` - but I think this should be possible some faster, or?

Comment: @BastianEbeling hundreds of lines or hundreds of columns?

Comment: Hi Dan, in my comment I ment hundreds of lines. But (as in my last edit, which you might not have seen) there could also occur many columns.

Comment: @BastianEbeling Well lines obviously isn't a problem, just replace the `4` with `length(C)`, for the columns, I think your best bet is a simple for loop, so if `col` is the loop variable and `C = celldata{:, col}` then  `[point(1:length(C), col).(C{1})] = C{2:end}`

Comment: Within my programming I always try to prevent the use of for loops. In my lines up above there is no need for a for-loop or the length-checking.  Your last examples for the columns is not working within R2013a.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29091/discussion-between-bastian-ebeling-and-dan)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) with cell arrays as input:

```
C = cellfun(@(x,y,z)[x y z], celldata(:,2), celldata(:,3), celldata(:,4), 'Uniform', 0);
point = struct('name', celldata(:, 1), 'posxyz', C);
```

Notice that for the `posxyz` field I've created a new cell array by catenating the cells of `celldata`.

If you want to add another field later, you can use [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) and [comma-separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). The following example stores the values from the fourth column of `celldata` in a new field, called `pos_z`:

```
[point(:).pos_z] = deal(celldata{:, 4});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a really fine idea. In my case there are many more columns - and for readability I wanted to add each column (or pair of columns like in xyz) in one source-code line. Do you know a way to add fields to your created point-structure?

Comment: @BastianEbeling Of course. You'll need to use [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) and [comma-separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). See the revised answer.